# Bootstrap EC2 Instance at launch to install awslogs

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to implement the following Script into a Launchtemplate to launch EC2 Instances with awslogs installed and ready:

```
    UserData:
      "Fn::Base64": !Sub >-
          #!/bin/bash -xe
          yum install -y aws-cfn-bootstrap
          /opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v --region ${AWS::Region} --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource BastionHostLaunchtemplate --region ${AWS::Region}
          # Install the CloudWatch Logs agent
          yum -y install awslogs
          service awslogs start
          chkconfig awslogs on
```

But when I connect to the instance afterwards via SSH and check I get this:

```
 [ec2-user@ip-172-16-47-249 ~]$ sudo service awslogsd status
 Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status awslogsd.service
 Unit awslogsd.service could not be found.
 [ec2-user@ip-172-16-47-249 ~]$
```

How can I bootstrap the EC2 Instances correctly?

merci A

Comment: Could it be due to duplicate `region` parameter on cfn-init? Are you actually using `AWS::CloudFormation::Init` for anything? What happens if you try to run these lines one by one on a new instance?

Comment: @tyron  actually yes I need the AWS::CloudFormation::Init, I want to mount an EFS Storage into the instance, but want to set it up step by step - so removed the metadata section for now..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These days, you should use **CloudWatch Agent**, which has replace the CloudWatch Logs agent (`awslogs`).

```
wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/amazoncloudwatch-agent/amazon_linux/amd64/latest/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.rpm

yum install amazon-cloudwatch-agent.rpm

/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl -a fetch-config -m ec2 -c file:configuration-file-path -s
```

See: [Getting Started: Installing the CloudWatch Agent on Your First Instance - Amazon CloudWatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/install-CloudWatch-Agent-on-first-instance.html#download-CloudWatch-Agent-on-EC2-Instance-first)

Comment: do you have by any chance a “tested” script I can use to install it using **UserData**? Merci in advance

Comment: Updated answer with a install script.

Comment: thank you; shouldnt I add this as well:
                   ```service awslogs start
                   chkconfig awslogs on``` or is this also only working for the old version; if so is there a new version? What I want to make sure is, that the service starts and restarts if the instance restarts. merci A

Comment: The last line in my code (above) apparently both configures and starts the agent. You should not use `awslogs` -- that is old and outdated.